# Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'after upgrading Android Studio to 3.0

Tags: android, gradle

This is an project my friend and I developed when I was using Android Studio 2.3.1. After upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 . This error occurred:

```
Error:Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'.
```

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I read a lot of errors and their solutions here , and I noticed event I changed `ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'` doesn't help

here are the gradle scripts:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.7.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-
plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they  
belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.joinme"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'


compile 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove plugin `apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'` in android 3.0

Instead use this

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```